# Implementing COM event sinks in a legacy Win32 Application

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl

I have a legacy Win32 application (WndProcs, etc) that needs to consume a COM object. With the use of a little ATL headers and some smart pointers that was a snap, however what I'm currently struggling with is how best to sink the events coming off that COM object?

My current working plan has been to build a second COM object (as a dll) that handles all the sinking and uses windows messages to communicate with the legacy application. This is "ok" but there's a lot of cruft moving messages back and forth to make the legacy application do what I want.

Is there a readily accessible way to get the Win32 legacy application to sink COM events directly vs running through the second "sinker" com object?

Before I go to far down this process I wanted to see if anyone else ran across this before and had a working solution.

Thanks!

Comment: "...to sink COM events directly..." : *where* ? A connection point design *requires* an *interface* pointer to which it sends its events after said-interface is registered via a call to [`Advise()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694318(v=vs.85).aspx). That's how connection points work. If you're asking whether you have to *implement* the COM object on which that event target interface hangs as a DLL-based inproc server, the answer is no, but you need an interface regardless. How you provide that interface is entirely up to you.

Comment: ATL [`IDispEventImpl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06wtz4t5.aspx) accepts "typical" ActiveX control events delivered via connection points and `IDispatch::Invoke`.

Comment: What compiler is being used for the legacy application?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled across this excellent write up by the always brilliant Raymond Chen.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/12/10425215.aspx

As WhozCraig indicated above, all I needed was the Interface pointer and to setup the Advise, handle the Invoke.

Nice and clean.

Thanks!

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you. I was actually quite close, but didn't know what to do with the other functions in IDispatch. Turns out. Nothing! ^^